# Is this a valid proof of the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I couldn't see this proof anywhere else online and it seems rather simplistic but I was wondering if it is valid and if not why. Apologies if I don't format the proof thoroughly I haven't had to do it before and don't know the proper terminology/notation.

suppose f(x) takes a maximum value (M) and a minimum value (m) on  the interval [a,b] meaning that all values between M and m are "covered" on the function between a and b. Therefore:

$$m(b-a)\le\int_a^bf(x)dx\le M(b-a)$$
$$\Rightarrow m\le\frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{(b-a)}\le M$$

since all values between M and m are covered on the function between a and b this means that $\frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{(b-a)}$ exists on the function between a and be as the function of some point c meaning that
$$f(c)=\frac{\left[\int f(x)dx\right]_a^b}{(b-a)}$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{d}{dx}f(c)=\frac{1}{(b-a)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int f(b)dx-\int f(a)dx \right]$$
$$\Rightarrow f^{'}(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)}$$

Comment: Well, you have actually proved another theorem which is *Mean Value Theorem for Integrals* which is somewhat similar to the usual mean value theorem for derivatives. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801733/72031) for a detailed discussion on these these two theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The equality$$f(c)=\frac{\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx}{b-a}$$is an equality between two *numbers*. The only conclusion that you can obtain deriving both sides with respect to $x$ is that $0=0$.

Comment: ah I see. Is the proof valid up to that point though. If so is there a correct way to complete that final step

Comment: @cal Yes, it is correct up to that point (except that you should state clearly that at a certain point you are using the continuity of $f$). What you got is one of the so-called mean value theorems for integrals. But I don't believ that you can finish a proof starting from this.

Comment: thanks again, is there a name for the theorem I ended up with (albeit with an incorrect method)?

Comment: @cal It's the [first mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals).

Answer (score 1):

This can't possibly be a correct proof since you haven't correctly used the fact that $f$ is differentiable. You do seem to know that it's continuous when you say

> all values between $M$ and $m$ are "covered"

So the $c$ you want does really exist.

But $c$ is a particular number. Then so is $f(c)$. If you differentiate that number with respect to $x$ you get just plain $0$.